# System completely unusable after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: upgrade, usb, system-installation, fglrx, 14.10

I can't use my PC anymore after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10. The download and upgrade process was good but now when I turn the PC on, I get a black screen with error:

> system program problem detected

And two options: **Cancel** and **Report problem**.

I can only use the mouse but the desktop is black and there are no icons. I can't activate Terminal. I read various posts on the web and followed different guides, but haven't solved the problem.

I can't even install a new version of Ubuntu starting from a bootable USB. When the system starts instead of booting the live version of Ubuntu, I get the GRUB menu ( ! ) ( I've never used Grub on my system ). When I select Ubuntu, the start-up process starts, but I get the error:

> 4.129466 i8042: no controller found

What is my problem? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have an AMD graphics card? If so, were you using the fglrx drivers? There has been an issue with them lately on this new update, as some packages needed for the driver to work correctly weren't updated to Utopic. In this case, open up tty1 (Terminal 1) by hitting the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, log in with an account that has sudo privileges and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx-*
```

This should solve the black screen problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: It does work! Now the screen is very large and I can't see my entire desktop, but now it works! I'll let you know if I have any more problems. Thank you very much! (sorry for my previous entry)

Comment: @DanieleSemeraro If you are still experiencing the large desktop, check: If you are not using any workspaces, and that your resolution is set to the correct value.

Comment: Unfortunately I've made a big mess. Ubuntu upper menu and left dock not showing. I searched the internet for a solution and I unfortunately disabled INTEGRATED GRAPHICS in the CMOS. Now the pc turns on but I can't see anything on my tv attached via hdmi cable. Can you help me? I also opened the case, sconnected and riconnected the battery but nothing happens. I can't find a jumper that resets the CMOS. How can I solve this big problem? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am searching for a solution, for the time being, install up gnome-session-flashback via aptitude and use the Gnome Flashback Metacity in the lightdm screen. Use tty1 if you prefer in the case.

Comment: I succeeded in resetting the CMOS. Now I turn my pc on and I only get the Ubuntu 14.10 splash screen (with four white dots). System seems to be freezed. Is there a way to reinstall everything? I tried with a usb stick with two different usb sticks (with 14.10 and 14.04) but every time the system starts I get a grub menu, I go on with Ubuntu and I get the freezed Ubuntu 14.10 splash screen.

Comment: If you really want to reinstall Ubuntu, follow: Do you have a BIOS or OpenFirmware? If so, you could go to the BIOS and boot by the Live USB or Live CD option. Go there, backup your files, format the partitions but do not destroy them, open the installer in the Live CD desktop and it should start.

Comment: I tried several things.  After I rebooted, after running the above line, my system was in the desired state.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I followed this advice, got back graphical access, but error message indicated underlying conflicts. So then reinstalled xorg elements using Synaptic packager, now can use while waiting for update repairing fglrx install.  Thanks, bob

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is still not solved after more conventional suggestions from others, please try the following.

1. Remove your hard drive and attach it to an external USB drive adapter case appropriate to its size and interface, ie [SATA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ITDSN5Y), or [mSATA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I4701O6), etc.
2. Attach it to another computer and try to instruct that computer to boot to your drive as though it were (and it is) an external usb drive.
3. See if it boots correctly.  If it does, it suggests that something related to your graphics card of your current PC is not entirely compliant with the drivers which were installed in the upgrade.  Fortunately, you will have access to drive to undriver it either using apt commands or my preference, the Synaptic Package Manager.